# (i'm beginner) Why when I clicking the register button redirect me to the register_db.php page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

**when i clicking register button ,it redirect me to register_db.php page. Why isn't the data being sent to the database and the web page still remains at register.php? I want the data to be sent to the database and the webpage not to change to register_db.php but to remain on the same register.php page as before.**

register.php

```
<?php 

    session_start();
    require_once 'config/db.php';

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>register</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="background">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center min-vh-100">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                        <div class="card shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded">
                            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <form action="register_db.php" method="POST">
                                        <div class="mb-3">
                                            <label for="username-form" class="form-label">Username</label>
                                            <input type="username" class="form-control" name="username"
                                                placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="username">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mb-3">
                                            <label for="password-form" class="form-label">Password</label>
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"
                                                placeholder="Password">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mb-3">
                                            <label for="confirm-password-form" class="form-label">Confirm Password</label>
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_password"
                                                placeholder="Confirm Password">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

register_db.php

```
<?php 

    session_start();
    require_once 'config/db.php';

    if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];
        $urole = 'user';

        if (empty($username)) {
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'กรุณากรอก Username';
            header("location: register.php");
        } else if (empty($password)) {
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'กรุณากรอกรหัสผ่าน';
            header("location: register.php");
        } else if (strlen($_POST['password']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['password']) < 8) {
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'รหัสผ่านต้องมีความยาวระหว่าง 8 ถึง 20 ตัวอักษร';
            header("location: register.php");
        } else if (empty($confirm_password)) {
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'กรุณายืนยันรหัสผ่าน';
            header("location: register.php");
        } else if ($password != $confirm_password) {
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'รหัสผ่านไม่ตรงกัน';
            header("location: register.php");
        } else {
            try {

                $check_username = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username");
                $check_username->bindParam(":username", $username);
                $check_username->execute();
                $row = $check_username->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                if ($row['username'] == $username) {
                    $_SESSION['warning'] = "ขื่อผู้ใช้นี้อยู่ในระบบแล้ว <a href='register.php'>คลิ๊กที่นี่</a> เพื่อเข้าสู่ระบบ";
                    header("location: register.php");
                } else if (!isset($_SESSION['error'])) {
                    $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username, password, urole) 
                                            VALUES(:username, :password, :urole)");
                    $stmt->bindParam(":username", $username);
                    $stmt->bindParam(":password", $passwordHash);
                    $stmt->bindParam(":urole", $urole);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $_SESSION['success'] = "สมัครสมาชิกเรียบร้อยแล้ว! <a href='login.php' class='alert-link'>คลิ๊กที่นี่</a> เพื่อเข้าสู่ระบบ";
                    header("location: register.php");
                } else {
                    $_SESSION['error'] = "มีบางอย่างผิดพลาด";
                    header("location: register.php");
                }

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }


?>
```

i want fix this problem

Comment: The behavior you're describing is expected and correct behavior for submitting a form.  It sounds like you want to submit the data in the background from JavaScript code without navigating the user.  For that, the technology you're looking for is called AJAX.

Comment: because it is a submit button, and there is no HTML or JS form validation on submiting

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of options here.

1. you redirect from register_db.php after your server side logic back to register.php
2. you make an ajax call to register_db.php to stay on the same page while sending data.
3. in your form, change register_db.php to register.php and make the server side logic on the same page.